# Oracle BPM: "Error while reading wsdl file .. file not found"

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper, business-process-management

I am going through step-by-step tutorial on creating Hello World Application BPM 11g where I am running into WSDL Read Error message. The link for this tutorial is here:

Building Your First Process with Oracle BPM 11g

Error occurs at chapter "Enhancing the Basic Hello World Process" -> Adding a Business Rule -> Step 5.

After creating Data Associations for input/output under Implementation dialog for "Review Needed" business rule and clicking on OK of the Properties dialog, I get following error message(please click on the link to see screenshot of error message):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1YDzO9g_MoLNkVTazdXTHp2UVE/edit?usp=sharing

Let me know if you have trouble accessing this link.

Basically the error is about not able to find decision service wsdl file:

Error while reading wsdl file:

ReviewRules_DecisionService_1.wsdl file not found

Also get same error for HelloRules_DecisionService_1.wsdl file not found.

I am not sure whether this file should be automatically generated when performing data associations and implementation of the business rule in the wizard.

Please let me know what could be going wrong here. I tried going through this tutorial multiple times but get stuck at this step.

BPM Suite 11g
BPMN Editor 11.1.1.7.0.0.97
Jdev version: 11.1.1.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer here https://community.oracle.com/thread/2355518 and basically the error is a bug of the platform regarding the xsd location

> i believe that is a bug in the composite editor. You MUST NOT copy ReviewObject.xsd from the businessCatalog folder to the xsd folder.
>
> Instead, try creating the Business Rule from the BPMN process. This can be done from the "Implementation" dialog of the Business Rule activity.
> In that dialog, you can specify the input and output of the Business Rule by dragging&dropping from the Process Data Objects into that dialog.
> There is no need to even look at the XSD, it is all hidden under the covers.
> Not sure why the tutorial wants you to create the rules component from the composite editor, i will check and get that fixed.

This is working for me!
And if you are following the last revision of the tutorial you can delete the HelloObject.xsd and ReviewObject.xsd frm the xsd folder before you create the business rule and link it to the businessrule activity... Then you can copy back the two files in that directory. Yes, it's weird, but  it'a a bug of the platform.

Answer (score -1):

I have created the Object Types and Process Data Objects manually without importing the xsd into project. There were no files on xsd directory regard to `HelloObject`/`ReviewObject` and I did not use the composite to create the rules, I did directly on Process Designer. The project deployed and it is working.